Creating a custom color for text-primary in darkmode
I'm pulling my hair out with this. I'm trying to follow the bootstrap docs for version 5.3.3
I've created a custom theme all started off well. Until I hit the dark mode switch. I noticed some of the colours worked in light mode but not dark(accessibility issues on contrast) so I'm trying to fix some of them when the user selects dark mode.
Mainly some text where i have used the class text-primary to make it red. But in dark mode its hard to read so where ever the class text-primarys been used in light mode when in dark mode make it green for eaxmple.
But everything i try doesnt work for the text :( heres my scss sheet.
`// Custom.scss
// Option A: Include all of Bootstrap

// Include any default variable overrides here (though functions won't be available)

//BOOTSTRAP Primary Color Overides
$primary: #e4002b;
$secondary: #706f6f;
$success: #c4d600;
$info: #0072ce;
$warning: #ffc72c;
$danger: #a70000;
$light: #b2b2b2;
$dark: #060202;

// ************Links************
//

// LIGHT MODE
$link-color: #000;

// ************DARK MODE************
//
//LINKS
$link-color-dark: #fff;
$text-color-dark: #00ff0d;

// ************Accordion************
$accordion-button-bg: transparent;
$accordion-button-active-bg: transparent;


// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';

@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';


Tried everything from posts on here to chattgpt but nothing seems to work.`


Check that your variable names match the names in Bootstrap. You’re using $text-color-dark but Bootstrap uses $body-color-dark so the Bootstrap value isn’t getting overridden. Also, you’ve intermixed Bootstrap’s Option 1 & Option 2 – you don’t need to include the functions and variable files. Those are imported in the bootstrap.scss file.

Thank you for your advice Rich. Thats worked and ive cleaned up my scss sheet like you said. But any text where I have set a class of text-primary doesn't change thats the text i want to change the colour of in dark mode as its giving me accessibility issues. Is there a class I can target to change the color of the class .text-primary when in dark mode?

Bootstrap sets the text color at the body using color: var(--bs-body-color); The custom property is set at the root as either --bs-body-color: #212529; or using a media query for dark mode to override the text color with --bs-body-color: #dee2e6;
